# Unexpected token, expected "}" at my countText case

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

Please bear with me as I am new to all of this and this is my first posted question! I am trying to set up a simple "welcome screen" with a signup button , and am just learning the ios/App development process/ react-native and javascript. Can anyone explain exactly why there is an error at the line 68? I got this error previously and thought it may be because I was "calling"the styles outside of the class, but I believe that is only an issue if this were a function and not a class? 
Error Reads: Failed to load bundle(http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?
platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false) with error:(SyntaxError: /Users/name/appname/App.js: Unexpected token, expected “}” (68:13)

```
type Props = {};

export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        backgroundColor: "#F5FCFF"
      },
      welcome: {
        fontSize: 20,
        textAlign: "center",
        margin: 10
      },
      instructions: {
        textAlign: "center",
        color: "#333333",
        marginBottom: 10
      },
      button: {
        alignItems: "center",
        backgroundColor: "blue",
        width: 100,
        padding: 10
      },
      countText: {
        padding: 20,
        color: "#FF00FF"
      }
    });
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to P2P Blockchain!</Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>To get started, click below!</Text>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button} onPress={this.onPress}>
            <Text> Sign Up Here! </Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
          <View style={[styles.countContainer]}>
            <Text style={[styles.countText]}>
              {this.state.count !== 0 ? this.state.count : null}
            </Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You have a `.` after your `container {`, you are missing `,` after your styles in `button` and `countText`, and you have no closing `</View>` tag at the end of your JSX.

Comment: Even with this corrections, the issue is still not resolved - also my apologies, the commas and period were from rewriting the code here.

Comment: That's alright. Exactly what error are you getting?

Comment: I will attach the error message~

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, TouchableHighlight, Text } from 'react-native';

type Props = {};

class App extends Component<Props> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            count: 10,
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to P2P Blockchain!</Text>
                <Text style={styles.instructions}>To get started, click below!</Text>
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button} onPress={this.onPress}>
                        <Text> Sign Up Here! </Text>
                    </TouchableHighlight>
                    <View style={styles.countContainer}>
                        <Text style={styles.countText}>
                            {this.state.count !== 0 ? this.state.count : null}
                        </Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        backgroundColor: "#F5FCFF"
    },
    welcome: {
        fontSize: 20,
        textAlign: "center",
        margin: 10
    },
    instructions: {
        textAlign: "center",
        color: "#333333",
        marginBottom: 10
    },
    button: {
        alignItems: "center",
        backgroundColor: "blue",
        width: 100,
        padding: 10
    },
    countText: {
        padding: 20,
        color: "#FF00FF"
    }
});

export default App;
```